Why do ListView widgets move out of the Container when scrolled?
I placed a ListView in a Container with a certain height and I want the scrollable area to remain within this Container. In other words, scrolling will only be done within that Container and the rest will not be visible when scrolled. However, as can be seen in the picture, the scrolled widgets extend outside the Container and are visible very clearly.
Where could I be making a mistake?

import 'package:complete_app/util/styles.dart';
import 'package:complete_app/view/base/title_block.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

import '../../../util/images.dart';
import '../../base/setting_button.dart';

class MeditationScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final List<String> meditationMusicList = [
    "Meditasyon Müziği 1",
    "Meditasyon Müziği 2",
    "Meditasyon Müziği 3",
    "Meditasyon Müziği 4",
    "Meditasyon Müziği 5",
    "Meditasyon Müziği 6",
    "Meditasyon Müziği 7",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  top: 80,
                  right: 16,
                  child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        '14 Mart 2024',
                        style: poppinsSemiBold.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Bugün',
                        style: poppinsMedium.copyWith(
                            fontSize: 14, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
                ),
                Opacity(
                  opacity: 0.4,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 180,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: Image.asset(Images.meditationDarkBackground,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: TitleBlock(title: "Günün Meditasyonu"),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: Text("Meditasyon zamanını ve konunuzu girerek istediğiniz meditasyon müziği eşliğinde konunuz üzerinde odaklanabilirsiniz", textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: poppinsRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),),
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Container(
              height: 265,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.amber,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
              child: ClipRect(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  itemCount: meditationMusicList.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => SizedBox(height: 10),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return SettingButton(
                      buttonTitle: meditationMusicList[index],
                      iconPath: Images.playIcon,
                      onTap: () {
                        print('${meditationMusicList[index]} oynatılıyor...');
                      },
                      hasArrow: false,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}


I tried using ClipRect, I tried placing SingleChildScrollView in Column instead of ListView, I tried shrinkWrap, no matter what I did, I couldn't eliminate the problem.

I found the solution. I am sharing the solution for those who have other problems with this issue.
SOLUTION: The issue was resolved by wrapping the SettingButton widgets with a Material widget, which confines the ink splash effects of InkWell within its bounds. This prevents the visual overflow of ink effects outside of the ListView.
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';

import '../../util/styles.dart';

class SettingButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String buttonTitle;
  final String iconPath;
  final bool? isSwitchButton;
  final bool? hasSubText;
  final bool? hasArrow;
  final double? iconHeight;
  final void Function()? onTap;
  final void Function(bool)? switchAction;

  SettingButton(
      {required this.buttonTitle,
        required this.iconPath,
        required this.onTap,
        this.isSwitchButton,
        this.hasSubText,
        this.switchAction, this.hasArrow = true, this.iconHeight = 15});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: onTap,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        child: Ink(
          height: 45,
          width: double.infinity,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(width: 16),
              Container(
                height: 30,
                width: 30,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xFFD9D9D9),
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: SvgPicture.asset(
                    iconPath,
                    color: Color(0xFF1E1E1E),
                    height: iconHeight,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 16),
              Text(
                buttonTitle,
                style: poppinsRegular.copyWith(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
              ),
              Spacer(),
              if (isSwitchButton != true)
                if (hasSubText == true)
                  Text(
                    'Türkçe',
                    style:
                    poppinsMedium.copyWith(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
              if (hasSubText == true) SizedBox(width: 5),
              if (isSwitchButton == true)
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 20,
                  child: Switch(
                    value: false,
                    onChanged: switchAction,
                    inactiveThumbColor: Colors.white,
                    inactiveTrackColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                    materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
                  ),
                )
              else if (hasArrow == true)
                Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  size: 20,
                ),
              SizedBox(width: 16),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

